# How to save the file in a specified location and display the contents of the downloaded text file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

After clicking on update button, the textarea allows to enter text. After entering text in text area and clicking on save button, the entered text is saved/downloaded to a text file under downloads. I am unable to save it under a specified path, how to do that?
And how to display the contents of the file back to textarea in HTML file?
Code:

```
<script>
function enableEditMode() {
var textBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
textBox.readOnly = false;
// Function to handle the button click event
}
function disableEditMode() {
var textBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
textBox.readOnly = true;
// Get the data from the textarea
var data = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;   
// Create a new Blob object
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });  
// Create a temporary anchor element
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = 'mgmtsummary.txt';    
// Append the anchor element to the body
document.body.appendChild(a);   
// Trigger a click event on the anchor element
a.click();    
// Remove the anchor element from the body
document.body.removeChild(a);    
// Attach the click event listener to the button
document.getElementById('saveButton').addEventListener('click', saveDataToFile);
}   
</script>
HTML:
<textarea id="myTextBox" readonly rows="8" cols="50">
* This is test.
* This is something.
* This is also something.
</textarea> 
<button onclick="enableEditMode()">Update</button>
<button onclick="disableEditMode()">Save</button>
```

[image: Update & Save buttons]
[image: Textarea description]

Comment: Why the python flag?